# add a number to a column in a text file -- linux awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

Im attempting to add the number 128 to each line in column 6 of my file below_zn.pdb that contains 128 lines, and 12 columns separated by spaces, not tab delimited. When I use

```
awk '{ $6+=128; print }' below_zn.pdb
```

I am able to add 128 to column 6, but the formatting of my file changes. My output looks as follows:

```
ATOM 1 ZN ZN2 H 129 -13.264 34.400 10.700 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 2 ZN ZN2 H 130 -13.264 25.273 10.700 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 3 ZN ZN2 H 131 -13.264 43.527 10.700 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 4 ZN ZN2 H 132 -13.264 52.654 10.700 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 5 ZN ZN2 H 133 -13.175 29.836 14.467 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 6 ZN ZN2 H 134 -13.175 38.963 14.467 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 7 ZN ZN2 H 135 -13.175 48.090 14.467 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 8 ZN ZN2 H 136 -13.175 57.217 14.467 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 9 ZN ZN2 H 137 -10.679 34.400 -15.527 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 10 ZN ZN2 H 138 -10.679 25.273 -15.527 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 11 ZN ZN2 H 139 -10.679 43.527 -15.527 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 12 ZN ZN2 H 140 -10.679 52.654 -15.527 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 13 ZN ZN2 H 141 -10.590 29.836 -11.760 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 14 ZN ZN2 H 142 -10.590 38.963 -11.760 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 15 ZN ZN2 H 143 -10.590 48.090 -11.760 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 16 ZN ZN2 H 144 -10.590 57.217 -11.760 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 17 ZN ZN2 H 145 -9.288 34.400 1.958 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 18 ZN ZN2 H 146 -9.288 25.273 1.958 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 19 ZN ZN2 H 147 -9.288 43.527 1.958 1.00 0.00 HETA
ATOM 20 ZN ZN2 H 148 -9.288 52.654 1.958 1.00 0.00 HETA
```

I need to keep the formatting for my file to be useful. I have tried

```
awk -F'()' '{ $6+=128; print }' below_zn.pdb
```

but instead of adding the number 128 to all lines of column 6, I am seeing a new column at the farthest right made of the number 128 repeatedly. As seen below:

```
ATOM      1  ZN  ZN2 H   1     -13.264  34.400  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA       128
ATOM      2  ZN  ZN2 H   2     -13.264  25.273  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA       128
ATOM      3  ZN  ZN2 H   3     -13.264  43.527  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA       128
ATOM      4  ZN  ZN2 H   4     -13.264  52.654  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA       128
ATOM      5  ZN  ZN2 H   5     -13.175  29.836  14.467  1.00  0.00      HETA       128
ATOM      6  ZN  ZN2 H   6     -13.175  38.963  14.467  1.00  0.00      HETA       128
```

Is there a way I can use `awk/sed/grep` or any other command in linux to add 128 to my numbers in column 6 while keeping the formatting as follows:

```
ATOM      1  ZN  ZN2 H   1     -13.264  34.400  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM      2  ZN  ZN2 H   2     -13.264  25.273  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM      3  ZN  ZN2 H   3     -13.264  43.527  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM      4  ZN  ZN2 H   4     -13.264  52.654  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM      5  ZN  ZN2 H   5     -13.175  29.836  14.467  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM      6  ZN  ZN2 H   6     -13.175  38.963  14.467  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM      7  ZN  ZN2 H   7     -13.175  48.090  14.467  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM      8  ZN  ZN2 H   8     -13.175  57.217  14.467  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM      9  ZN  ZN2 H   9     -10.679  34.400 -15.527  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM     10  ZN  ZN2 H  10     -10.679  25.273 -15.527  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM     11  ZN  ZN2 H  11     -10.679  43.527 -15.527  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM     12  ZN  ZN2 H  12     -10.679  52.654 -15.527  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM     13  ZN  ZN2 H  13     -10.590  29.836 -11.760  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM     14  ZN  ZN2 H  14     -10.590  38.963 -11.760  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM     15  ZN  ZN2 H  15     -10.590  48.090 -11.760  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM     16  ZN  ZN2 H  16     -10.590  57.217 -11.760  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM     17  ZN  ZN2 H  17      -9.288  34.400   1.958  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM     18  ZN  ZN2 H  18      -9.288  25.273   1.958  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM     19  ZN  ZN2 H  19      -9.288  43.527   1.958  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM     20  ZN  ZN2 H  20      -9.288  52.654   1.958  1.00  0.00      HETA
.
.
.
```

An important note is that column 7 through 9 can have up to 7 characters (whole number with a period followed by the decimal), and there is one space separating the columns.
My file has the following format
column 1 - 4 characters
1 space
column 2 - 1 character
1 space
column 3 - 2 characters
1 space
column 4 - 1 character
1 space
column 5 - 3 characters
1 space
column 6 - 1,2,or 3 characters
5 spaces
column 7 - up to 7 characters
1 space
column 8 - up to 7 characters
1 space
column 9 - up to 7 characters
2 spaces
column 10 - 4 characters
2 spaces
column 11 - 4 characters
6 spaces
column 12 - 4 characters
end of file

Thank you!

Comment: please update the question to show the (wrong) outputs generated by your code attempts, also show the (correct) expected output; also helpful would be a description of your column delimiters (doesn't look like tabs; looks live a variable number of spaces)

Comment: Why have you used `print` and `1` (which effectively repeats the print)? Otherwise, I get the sum required in column 6 using `awk '{ $6+=128; print }'  file`

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- input is using fixed-width spacing
- white space only shows up as a column delimiter (ie, no column values contain white space)
- the values in column 6 are left-justified

Adding a new row to demonstrate a wider value for column 6:

```
$ cat below_zn.pdb
ATOM      1  ZN  ZN2 H   1     -13.264  34.400  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM      2  ZN  ZN2 H   2     -13.264  25.273  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM      3  ZN  ZN2 H   3     -13.264  43.527  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM      4  ZN  ZN2 H   4     -13.264  52.654  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM      5  ZN  ZN2 H   5     -13.175  29.836  14.467  1.00  0.00      HETA
BUBBLE  206  ZN  ZN2 H   7000  -13.175  29.836  14.467  1.00  0.00      HETA-HETA
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { regex1="^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){5}"                  # match 1st 5 columns plus trailing white space
        regex2="[^[:space:]]+"                                    # match non-white space characters (aka 6th column)
      }
      { oldline=$0

        match(oldline,regex1)                                     # find 1st 5 columns
        newline=substr(oldline,1,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)                # save 1st 5 columns for new line
        oldline=substr(oldline,RSTART+RLENGTH)                    # strip off 1st 5 columns

        match(oldline,regex2)                                     # match 1st column of shortened line (aka 6th column of original line)
        newval=substr(oldline,1,RLENGTH) + 128                    # extract column and add 128
        newlen=length(newval)                                     # get length of new value
        newline=newline newval substr(oldline,RSTART+newlen)      # append new value and rest of line to newline

        print newline                                             # print newline to stdout
      }
' below_zn.pdb
```

This generates:

```
ATOM      1  ZN  ZN2 H   129   -13.264  34.400  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM      2  ZN  ZN2 H   130   -13.264  25.273  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM      3  ZN  ZN2 H   131   -13.264  43.527  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM      4  ZN  ZN2 H   132   -13.264  52.654  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA
ATOM      5  ZN  ZN2 H   133   -13.175  29.836  14.467  1.00  0.00      HETA
BUBBLE  206  ZN  ZN2 H   7128  -13.175  29.836  14.467  1.00  0.00      HETA-HETA
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much. This approaches exactly what I am needing. The only issue is that when my second column changes from 1 digit to 2 digits, and then from 2 digits to 3 digits, there is an issue with the spacing of the 6th column. I could easily fix it in vi for this small file, but I wanted to understand how to modify this for when I use this piece of code you came up with for a longer file.

Comment: based on your newly updated question and the larger set of input data ... the issue isn't with the number of digits in the 2nd or 6th columns; the issue appears to be related to the numbers in the 6th column being `right-justified` while my 3rd assumptions was that the 6th column is `left-justified`; since the answer works for the original question and dataset I'd recommend ... 1) upvote and/or accept the answer as it addresses the original question and 2) if you're unable to tweak this answer to address the larger data set (and the `right-/left-justification` issue) then ask a new question ..

Comment: if you ask a new question keep in mind that providing a more representative set of data (in this case demonstrating different width values in all pertinent columns) increases the chance of getting a more robust solution

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
ATOM      1  ZN  ZN2 H   1     -13.264  34.400  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA  
ATOM      2  ZN  ZN2 H   2     -13.264  25.273  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA  
ATOM      3  ZN  ZN2 H   3     -13.264  43.527  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA  
ATOM      4  ZN  ZN2 H   4     -13.264  52.654  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA  
ATOM      5  ZN  ZN2 H   5     -13.175  29.836  14.467  1.00  0.00      HETA
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*";OFS=""}{$6=($6+128) "  ";print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
ATOM      1  ZN  ZN2 H   129  -13.264  34.400  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA  
ATOM      2  ZN  ZN2 H   130  -13.264  25.273  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA  
ATOM      3  ZN  ZN2 H   131  -13.264  43.527  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA  
ATOM      4  ZN  ZN2 H   132  -13.264  52.654  10.700  1.00  0.00      HETA  
ATOM      5  ZN  ZN2 H   133  -13.175  29.836  14.467  1.00  0.00      HETA
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field is one-or-more (`+`) non (`^`) whitespace (`[:space:]`) characters, followed by zero-or-more (`*`) whitespace chcaracters, therefore trailing whitespace will become part of field and that output field separator (`OFS`) is empty string. Then for each line regarding 6th column I increase value by 128 and concatenate with two spaces, after that I `print` line. Feel free to adjust required number of spaces.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*